# The reason for the fading of galaxies?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion, galaxies, doppler-effect

Galaxies that are greater than a distance of c/H metres from Earth have recessional velocities exceeding the speed of light and begin to fade. Thus, theoretical astronomers 3 trillion years the future will see only the Milky Way in the night sky. What is the reason for this fading of galaxies?

Comment: Because the universe is expanding. Really isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: Galaxies that have recessional velocity exceeding c are beginning to fade away: I am asking why they are fading away.

Comment: Because their light never reaches us (as soon as their recessional velocity exceeds c).

Comment: However what is the reason why the emitted light never reaches us?